# Static method access in abstract class/interface (flutter/dart)

Tags: flutter, class, dart, oop, interface

In my flutter project, I have the following abstract class.

```
abstract class Storage {
  static method1{}
  static method2{}
  ...
}
```

Then I define other classes that extend to Storage but each child class implements some of the methods defined (with empty body) in the Storage class.

```
class StorageA{
    static method1{ print("1") }
}
class StorageB{
    static method2{ print("2") }
}
```

My goal is to be able to call any of these static method by using the Storage namespace, however, I want to invoke the overridden methods in the child classes. For example, when I call `Storage.method1` it should print 1. This is a very simplified example but I normally have bunch of methods and I want to group these methods into different classes that extend to Storage. But at the same time i want to access all the overridden methods with Storage namespace. Currently when I do `Storage.method1` compiler picks up the function defined in Storage because it has an empty body. If i remove the body and turn it into function declaration, then I can't define the function as static. So, how can I reach my goal here?

Is combining everything into a single Storage class and defining the methods as static the only solution here?

Comment: `static` methods are the same thing as global, freestanding functions except that they're in a different scope.  They are not part of the class's interface, and they cannot be overridden.  Overriding static methods does not make much sense.  If code within `StorageA` makes an unqualified call to `method1()`, it will call `StorageA.method1()`.  If code from *outside* of `StorageA` attempts to call `Storage.method1()`, how do you expect `StorageA.method1()` to be called?  What there were some `StorageC` class that also implemented `method1?

Comment: You might be better served by making `Storage` have `Function` members and by having some initialization code that assigns those members to specific implementations in the `StorageA` or `StorageB` classes.